# WCF RESTful HTTPS support

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I have [WebInvoke] method which  use for ajax call to get data, but in some case ajax call should happens over HTTPS protocol.
How to configure my method to work with both HTTP and HTTPS connection

this is may method

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ChartService
    {           
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        public GetDataRes GetData(GetDataReq req)
        { 
            res=DB.GetRes(req);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

this is web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Won.ICom.Code.Services.ChartServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="Won.ICom.Code.Services.ChartService">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:12345/services/ChartService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="Won.ICom.Code.Services.ChartServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
             binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Won.ICom.Code.Services.ChartService" />
          </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html

Answer (score 0):

Create second End point
Change mexHttpBinding to mexHttpsBinding in the second end point.
In serviceMetadata, we also need to change httpGetEnabled to httpsGetEnabled.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:12345/services/ChartService.svc"      bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Won.ICom.Code.Services.ChartService" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>

<serviceBehaviors>
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
</serviceBehaviors>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
<binding name="TransportSecurity">
<security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```